# Adding a new version of spring-boot-starter-parent creates an issue with jetty server configuration

Tags: jetty, spring-boot-starter

After moving from

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I faced problems with my jetty server and client.
Which dependencies should I include into pom.xml after moving to the higher version of spring-boot-starter-parent?

Including other used dependencies as well

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>2.20.2</camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-soap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-client-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-el:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-starter:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf-transport:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.oauth.core:oauth-provider:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.oauth.core:oauth:jar:20100527:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-soap:jar:2.20.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:jar:2.20.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.20.2:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring:jar:2.20.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    \- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]       \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionManager

Comment: Edit your question to update it.  Please use `$ mvn dependency:tree` and show your project's dependency tree.  It seems like you either have mismatched dependencies, or missing dependencies.